# Why do I need to re-delegate the events of a child view every time the parent view is being re-rendered?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

Of course, this will dependent on how you re-render you parent view. The parent view instantiates all it's sub-view in the initialize phase and simply appends them/replaces an element after the template has been rendered. For example this is how I would do in the render method:

```
this.$('.InputSearch').replaceWith(this.inputSearchView.$el);
```

So this.inputSerchView is an instance that has been affected in the initialize method.

The problem is that after the line above has been executed, the events callbacks are not being called anymore in the inputSearchView, I need to do:

```
this.delegateEvents();
```

I don't know why I have to do this, since backbone does this in the background:

```
this.$el.on(eventName, selector, method);
```

this.$el never changes, so I don't know what's causing the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When re-rendering the view, this is executed:

```
view.$el.html(Handlebars.compile(view.template)(context));
```

The html method removes event handlers from the child elements (from the jQuery doc)

> Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event
>   handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the
>   new content.

This is why I have to rebind the elements/events

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `replaceWith` uses [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) and inserts the content before it, from jQuery's remove documentation

> In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.

hence you should rebind the events of view `el` elements which is done by the `delegateEvents` method.

Comment: Close enough! It actually helped me find the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `this.delegateEvents()` is called only once inside `Backbone.View` constructor and when you render it once it works well, but after second render you get this problem.

Options:

1. Initialize child views inside parent view `render()` method
2. Use `this.delegateEvents()` inside child view `render()` method